# regex pattern to allow positive and negative integers

Tags: regex, xsd

I am trying to find regex pattern in XSD that allow both positive and negative integers

My current code allows only positive integers.

```
xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,10}"
```

Comment: @ser3425746 can't you put optional minus in front?

Comment: Should the integers be allowed to start with a zero? Is `000129501` valid?

Comment: `""` is *not* a positive integer :-) You should probably start with `[0-9]{1,10}` or possibly better `[1-9][0-9]{0,9}` (assuming you want it length-limited) then whack a `-?` on the front for the optional negative sign.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you only mention an optional negative sign in front of the number:

```
xs:pattern value="-?[0-9]{0,10}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `\d` notation would make it even simpler:

```
xs:pattern value="-?\d+"
```

Answer (score -1):

if you using python:
example re.findall:

```
regex=re.findall(r'(-?[\d]+)',somestring)
```

*output:
[negative integer, integer]

Comment: The question is about XSD not python.

Comment: But actually the same meaning. Such as "-? (0-9) {0,9})" .. :)