# Regular Expression to allow only positive and negative integer

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an `angular grid`, which contains a textbox. I have to allow only positive and negative integers in the textbox. However, when I apply the `regular expression`, it expects a sign in front of the positive number as well. I do not wish to add any plus sign in front of the positive numbers.

In case, I enter `13`, the code considers `'1'` as a sign.

I have used the following regex:
^-[1-9]\d{0,2}$

How to resolve this?

Comment: put your code which you have tried?

Comment: which regular expression do you use?

Comment: try this ^-?\d*\.?\d+$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex pattern to allow positive and negative integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086045/regex-pattern-to-allow-positive-and-negative-integers)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below regular expression for that

```
/^[+-]?\d+$/
```

--Sample

HTML

```
<ul id = "results">
</ul>
```

JS

```
var numberExamples = [156, 12, +90, -34, "adf",11,-111,1.0,1.2,1.2,'1a','u8' ];

var pattern = /^[+-]?\d+$/;

$.each(numberExamples, function (index, numberExamples) {

  $("#results").append("<li>" + numberExamples + " = " + pattern.test(numberExamples) + "</li>");

});
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekt2sgm8/157/)

If you want to accept decimals also then go for the below regex

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/
```